# ng-file-upload cannot read property 'file' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, ng-file-upload

I am trying to use ng-file-upload https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

I have used the basic setup:

HTML:

```
<section ng-controller="MyController">

    <form name="form">
                    Single Image with validations
                    <div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="file" name="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
                    ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="20MB" ngf-min-height="100" 
                    ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}">
                        Select
                    </div>
                    Multiple files
                    <div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="files" ngf-multiple="true">
                        Select
                    </div>
                    Drop files:<div ngf-drop ng-model="files" class="drop-box">Drop</div>
                    <button type="submit" ng-click="submitUpload()">submit</button>
                </form>
</section>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngFileUpload'], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
});

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, RESTService) {


// upload later on form submit or something similar
$scope.submitUpload = function() {
  if ($scope.form.file.$valid && $scope.file) {
    $scope.submitUpload($scope.file);
  }
};

// upload on file select or drop
$scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: 'upload/url',
        data: {file: file, 'username': $scope.username}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
};

});
```

I am able to select a file via the windows browser, however, when I click submit, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined

Comment: Could you tell us which line of code you get the error on?

Comment: Sure, here: if ($scope.form.file.$valid && $scope.file) {

Answer (score 0):

Accompanying your question with a JSFiddle would be great.

Nevertheless, these lines of code could very well cause a problem:

```
// upload later on form submit or something similar
$scope.submitUpload = function() {
  if ($scope.form.file.$valid && $scope.file) {
    $scope.submitUpload($scope.file);
  }
};
```

I believe inside the **submitUpload** function you should have called the **upload** function, because otherwise you are just recursively calling the same function with an extra argument.

If that doesn't help your issue, let me know.